# Trying to schedule every x minutes function from class

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, schedule

I need help with something i cant fix.
I tried to call fuction from class every X minutes by use Schedule but not success. this is the error i got when i run the code :

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        #print('ok3')
        chrome_options = Options()  
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)



    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

    def login(self):
        print('Trying to login...')
        self.driver.get('xxxxx')
        elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("fld")
        button = self.driver.find_element_by_id("sgnBt")
        button.click()
        print("Login success")

    def dothis(self):
        print('Starting to fetch...')


MyClass1=MyClass()
MyClass1.login()

schedule.every(0.1).minutes.do(MyClass,MyClass1.dothis())

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\EDU Creator Pyhon (1)\EDU Creator Pyhon\ebay-new.py", line 193, in <module>
    schedule.run_pending()
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py", line 563, in run_pending
    default_scheduler.run_pending()
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py", line 94, in run_pending
    self._run_job(job)
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py", line 147, in _run_job
    ret = job.run()
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py", line 466, in run
    ret = self.job_func()
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 0):

```
schedule.every(0.1).minutes.do(MyClass,MyClass1.dothis())
```

You give 2 argument to schedule.do  (Myclass,MyClass.dothis())

give one argument.

For example :

```
schedule.every(0.1).minutes.do(MyClass1.dothis())
```

Comment: TypeError: the first argument must be callable